# Downloading Text From UrL

Tags: ios, swift

So I have a url link that has a text file with contents in it that I want to present in my app. However I am having a very hard time downloading it to my app. My code for trying to grab the text at the location currently looks like this

```
   @objc func grabTextFile(){
        let messageURL = URL(string: urlString)
        let sharedSession = URLSession.shared
        let downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTask(with: messageURL!,completionHandler: {
        (location: URL!, response: URLResponse!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            var urlContents = ""
            do{
                urlContents = try String(contentsOf: location, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            }catch {
                urlContents =  ""
            }
        print(urlContents)} as! (URL?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void)
        downloadTask.resume()
    }
```

message url is this link

> var urlString = "18.218.88.192:8080/ActiveHoneypotWeb/logfiles/159.65.139.103-0-commands.txt"

For some reason, it crashes every time.
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misuse of `!` is causing you lots of problems. But the ultimate cause of your problem is that `18.218.88.192:8080/ActiveHoneypotWeb/logfiles/159.65.139.103-0-commands.txt` isn't a valid URL. There is no scheme. Add `http://` or `https://` as needed to the start of the URL.

Here is how your code should be written. This properly checks for errors and nil values.

```
@objc func grabTextFile(){
    if let messageURL = URL(string: urlString) {
        let sharedSession = URLSession.shared
        let downloadTask = sharedSession.downloadTask(with: messageURL) { (location, response, error) in
            var urlContents = ""
            if let location = location {
                do{
                    urlContents = try String(contentsOf: location, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                }catch {
                    print("Couldn't load string from \(location)")
                }
            } else if let error = error {
                print("Unable to load data: \(error)")
            }
        }
        downloadTask.resume()
    } else {
        print("\(urlString) isn't a valid URL")
    }
}
```

Comment: I changed that and it still didn't work
could you maybe help me with the syntax of my function a little bit